# Does it exist a limit of quantity functions per modules in python?

Tags: python

good evening.
 I'm was building a play in python, and there's a module with many function. However, when I put one more function the python say " NameError: name 'get_update'(name_fuction) is not defined". Even though I defined the function and declared  this function as public I  put the function name in the **all** list and finally I use "from name_module import *" to import the correspondent module. So it doesn't make sense, the idle suggests for me the name function when I type it and the program doesn't recognize as I didn't have declared the function, but it is and it is public and I imported the correspondent module. But when I put the same function in the  other module and I did the same procedures, the  program recognized my function, so I conclude that exists a limit function quantity per module. Am I right???

the correspondent code is below if someone wanna see the code:

```
from jogador import *
from collections import Counter
quant_update = { "um" : 0 , "dois" : 0 , "tres": 0 , "quatro" : 0 , "cinco": 0 , "seis": 0, "trinca": 0 , "quadra": 0 ,"fullhouse":0,"yathezz": 0,
                 "seq_max": 0 , "seq_min": 0 , "chance":0}
__all__ = ["calc_Pontuacao","calc_Vencedor","get_upate"]

#SECÇAO SUPERIOR

def calc_Num(num,dados):
    i=0
    Soma=0;
    while(i<5):
        if(dados[i]==num):
            Soma=Soma+num
        i=i+1
    return Soma

#SECÇAO INFERIOR

# Se Trinca -> num = 3, Se Quadra -> num = 4
def calc_Rep(num,dados):
    Soma=0
    lista=Counter(dados).values()
    if(num in lista):
        Soma= dados[0] + dados[1] + dados[2] + dados [3] + dados[4]
    return Soma


def calc_FullHouse(dados):
    Pont=0
    lista=Counter(dados).values()
    if((2 in lista) and (3 in lista)):
        Pont=25
    return Pont

def calc_SeqMin(dados):
    Pont=0
    if ((1 and 2 and 3 and 4 in dados) or (2 and 3 and 4 and 5 in dados) or (3 and 4 and 5 and 6 in  dados)):        
        Pont=30
    return Pont

def calc_SeqMax(dados):
    Pont=0
    if ((1 and 2 and 3 and 4 and 5 in dados) or (2 and 3 and 4 and 5 and 6 in dados)):        
        Pont=40
    return Pont

def calc_Yathzee(dados,nome):
    if calc_Rep(5,dados)!=0:
        if get_Yahtzee(nome):
            return 100      
        else:
            return 50
    else:
        return 0

def calc_Chance(dados):
    if(quant_update["yathezz"] > 1):
        return dados[0] + dados[1] + dados[2] + dados [3] + dados[4]
    else:
        return 0

#TOTAL    

def calc_Pontuacao(dados,comp_tabela,nome):
    global quant_update
    comp_tabela=comp_tabela.lower()
    if comp_tabela=="um":
        if(quant_upate["um"] <=1):
            val=calc_Num(1,dados)
            quant_update["um"] +=1
    elif comp_tabela=="dois":
        if (quant_upate["dois"] <= 1):
            val=calc_Num(2,dados)
            quant_upate["dois"] += 1
    elif comp_tabela=="tres":
        if (quant_upate["tres"] <= 1):
            val=calc_Num(3,dados)
            quant_upate["tres"] += 1
    elif comp_tabela=="quatro":
        if (quant_upate["quatro"] <= 1):
            val=calc_Num(4,dados)
            quant_upate["quatro"] += 1
    elif comp_tabela=="cinco":
        if (quant_upate["cinco"] <= 1):
            quant_upate["cinco"] += 1
            val=calc_Num(5,dados)
    elif comp_tabela=="seis":
        if (quant_upate["seis"] <= 1):
            val=calc_Num(6,dados)
            quant_upate["seis"] += 1
    elif comp_tabela=="trinca":
        if (quant_upate["trinca"] <= 1):
            val=calc_Rep(3,dados)
            quant_upate["trinca"] += 1
    elif comp_tabela=="quadra":
        if (quant_upate["quadra"] <= 1):
            val=calc_Rep(4,dados)
            quant_upate["quadra"] += 1
    elif comp_tabela=="fullhouse":
        if (quant_upate["fullhouse"] <= 1):
            val=calc_FullHouse(dados)
            quant_upate["fullhouse"] += 1
    elif comp_tabela=="seqmin":
        if (quant_upate["seqmin"] <= 1):
            val=calc_SeqMin(dados)
            quant_upate["seqmin"] += 1
    elif comp_tabela=="seqmax":
        if (quant_upate["seqmax"] <= 1):
            val=calc_SeqMax(dados)
            quant_upate["seqmax"] += 1
    elif comp_tabela=="yahtzee":
        if (quant_upate["yahtzee"] <= 3):
            val=calc_Yahtzee(dados,nome)
            quant_upate["yahtzee"] += 1
    elif comp_tabela=="chance":
        if (quant_upate["chance"] <= 1):
            val=calc_Chance(dados)
            quant_upate["chance"] += 1
    if(checa_bonus()):
        val+=35

def checa_bonus():
    global quant_update
    soma =quant_update["um"] + quant_update["dois"] + quant_update["tres"] + quant_update["quatro"]+quant_update["cinco"] + quant_update["seis"]
    if(soma < 6):
        bonus = False
    else:
        bonus = True
    return bonus








def calc_PontSup(nome):
    lista=get_jogador(nome)
    Soma=0   
    while i<7:
        Soma= Soma + lista[1][0][i]
        i=i+1
    if Soma>62:
        Soma= Soma + 35
    return Soma


def calc_PontInf(nome):
    lista=get_jogador(nome)
    i=0
    j=0
    while i<5:
        Soma= Soma + lista[1][1][i]
        i=i+1
    while j<3:
        Soma= Soma + lista[1][1][5][j]
        j=j+1    
    Soma = Soma + lista[1][1][6]
    return Soma
def get_upate(comp_tab):
    global quant_update
    return quant_update[comp_tab]

def calc_PontTotal(nome):
    return calc_PontSup(nome) + calc_PontInf(nome)

def calc_Vencedor():
    i=0
    j=0
    PtMax=0
    pessoas=[]
    while(i<3):
        nome=get_nome_ind(i)
        Pt=calc_PontTotal(nome)
        pessoas.append([nome,Pt])
        if(Pt>PtMax):
            PtMax=Pt
        i=i+1
    print("O(s) vencedor(es) é(sao):")
    while(j<3):
        if(pessoas[j][1]==PtMax):
           print(pessoas[j][0])
```

the other module:

```
from random import *
from InstanciaJogo import *
from partida import *


__all__ = ["lanca_dados","identificaResultado"]

#lança dados 1 vez
def aux_dados(numDados):
    dados=[0]*numDados
    i=0
    a=0
    while(i< numDados):
        a=randint(1,6)
        dados[i]=a
        i=i+1
    return dados

#funçao que pega indices de dados p/ relancar e relanca dados
def relanca(d1,d2):
    i=0
    a=0
    #d1=[0,1,4]
    #d2=[5,3,1,1,4]
    print(d1,d2)
    print(len(d1))
    while(i<len(d1) - 1):
        a=d1[i]
        d2[a]=randrange(1,6)
        i=i+1
    identificaResultado(d2)
    return d2    

#fucao transformar lista de string em int
# ["3","4","5""] --> [3,4,5]
def str_Int(lista):
    i=0
    while(i<len(lista)):
        lista[i]=int(lista[i])
        i=i+1
    return lista
def identificaResultado(dados):
    resultados = []

    if( 1 in dados and get_upate("um") < 1):
        resultados.append("um")
    if (2 in dados and get_upate("dois") < 1):
        resultados.append("dois")
    if(3 in dados and get_upate("tres") < 1):
        resultados.append("tres")
    if(4 in dados and get_upate("quatro") < 1):
        resultados.append("quatro")
    if(5 in dados and get_upate("cinco") < 1):
        resultados.append("cinco")
    if(6 in dados and get_upate("seis") < 1):
        resultados.append("seis")
    if(calc_FullHouse(dados) != 0 and get_upate("fullhouse") < 1):
        resultados.append("fullhouse")
    if(calc_Rep(3,dados) != 0 and get_upate("trinca") < 1):
        resultados.append("trinca")
    if (calc_Rep(4, dados) != 0 and get_upate("quadra") < 1 ):
        resultados.append("quadra")
    if (calc_SeqMin(dados) !=0 and get_upate("seq_min") < 1):
        resultados.append("seq_min")
    if (calc_SeqMax(dados) != 0 and get_upate("seq_max") < 1):
        resultados.append("seq_max")
    if(calc_Yathzee(dados) != 0 and get_upate("yathezz") < 3 ):
        resultados.append("yathezz")
    if(calc_Chance(dados) !=0):
        resultados.append("chance")
    print("**** Possiveis Resultados  **** \n")
    print(resultados)


def lanca_dados(nome):
    dados=aux_dados(5)
    print(dados)
    #exibe_Possibilidades(dados,nome)

    identificaResultado(dados)
    resp=input("Jogar os dados novamente (S(Sim) ou N(Nao))?")
    if(resp=="N"):
        return dados
    else:
        respD=input("Quais os índices dos dados quer relançar?(Ex:0,3,4 - Sem espaço entre as vírgulas)")
        Dados_relanc=str_Int(respD.split(","))
        print(Dados_relanc)
        print("\n")
        relanca(Dados_relanc,dados)
        print(dados)
        #exibe_Possibilidades(dados,nome)
        resp=input("Jogar os dados novamente (S(Sim) ou N(Nao))?")
        if(resp=="N"):
            return dados
        else:
            respD=input("Quais os índices dos dados quer relançar?(Ex:0,3,4 - Sem espaço entre as vírgulas)")
            Dados_relanc=str_Int(respD.split(","))
            relanca(Dados_relanc,dados)
            print(dados)
            #exibe_Possibilidades(dados,nome)
            return dados
```

the main module

````
from InstanciaJogo import *
from partida import *
from jogador import *


def loop_jogo():
    i = 1
    j=0

    while(j<13):
        while(i <= get_num_jogadores()):
            nome=get_nome_ind(i)
            print("Vez de "+ nome)
            dados=lanca_dados(nome)

            secao_tab=input('Que secçao da tabela deseja escolher?(inferior ou superior)')
            comp_tabela=input('Que componente ta tabela deseja escolher?')
            val=calc_Pontuacao(dados,comp_tabela,nome)
            manipula_tabela(nome,secao_tab,comp_tabela,val)
            i=i+1
        j=j+1
    calc_Vencedor()
    resp=input("Deseja jogar novamente?(S(Sim) ou N(Nao)")
    if resp=='S':
        loop_jogo()

#test: Essa parte é descartável.
Inst_jogo()
print("Partidas: " + str(get_partidas()) +"\n" + "num_jogadores: " + str(get_num_jogadores()) + "\n" )
print(get_num_jogadores())
loop_jogo()


```
````

Comment: There seem to be multiple issues here. You appear to be mixing multiple naming conventions, which makes things quite confusing. It's probably best to just stick to `lower_case_with_underscores` for functions and variables. `(1 and 2 and 3 and 4 and 5 in dados)` does not behave as you expect. `import *` is almost always bad practice. There are tons of unnecessary parentheses. While I haven't taken a proper look, it's likely that the use of global variables can be reduced.

Comment: No, this is a spelling mistake as noted in the comments. Furthermore you should **never** use starred imports like this

Comment: I updated the script, indeed there was a spelling mistake. But the spelling mistake is not the main problem, because the same message  have been exhibited in the terminal " the function get_upate is not defined ".

Comment: Well, your suspicion that there is a limit to the number of functions in a module is not correct, so that definitely isn't the issue

Comment: so what's the problem?? The other functions in the "partida.py" were imported well and they are working well, but when I add one new function this error happens. Why  this error   is happening???

Comment: Quite frankly and with all due respect, your code is a mess and you haven't provide a reproducible example, let alone a [mcve], as is required. You haven't even provide the full error message and stack trace, which is invaluable for debugging. I have no idea which module is which, my *suspicion* is that `jogador.py` imports `InstanciaJogo.py` and you have a circular import, which would could cause this NameError. But you need to help us help you.

Comment: To be clear, I suspect you have a circular import, where one module imports another, and vice versa.

Comment: Exactly, I'm do it, with the 4 modules in my program.  Forgive  me, it's a little difficult for me describe with words, maybe  I've been unclear, this is a play, and I've separated this  this play in some modules. One for the play, one for the system (match), other to instantiate and another for the main.  The problem itself is in the import of one function in specific, some particular thing in python don't allow my import one more function from "partida.py" to other modules

Comment: Maybe my all code can describe better, because that I become my all code available at github in thi link: https://github.com/lucasvittal2/Yathezz

Comment: the problem is in the function "get_update";

Answer (score 1):

i think you have an issue of a spelling mistake. Take a look at this park of your code.

```
quant_update = { "um" : 0 , "dois" : 0 , "tres": 0 , "quatro" : 0 , "cinco": 0 , "seis": 0, "trinca": 0 , "quadra": 0 ,"fullhouse":0,"yathezz": 0,
                 "seq_max": 0 , "seq_min": 0 , "chance":0}
__all__ = ["calc_Pontuacao","calc_Vencedor","get_upate"]
```

used wrong spelling of **get_update as get_upate**. Updating it should solve your problem.

Comment: I fixed this problem. But the problem remains and I my suspicious too. I edited the code, now the stuff can be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I saw you mentioned that fixing the typo does not get rid of the issue. Unfortunately, as it stands debugging this program is going to be far more painful and tough than it should be. The program could be shortened significantly, and its readability greatly improved, which would both help prevent and fix bugs.

Therefore, here is a quick review of the style and design of the program, as well as some issues.

Here is the original comment I made, which mentions some issues:

> There seem to be multiple issues here. You appear to be mixing multiple naming conventions, which makes things quite confusing. It's probably best to just stick to lower_case_with_underscores for functions and variables. (1 and 2 and 3 and 4 and 5 in dados) does not behave as you expect. import * is almost always bad practice. There are tons of unnecessary parentheses.

---

### `from ___ import *`

`import *` offers virtually nothing to offset the massive downsides it brings. It makes it incredibly tough to follow the program and figure out where functions and classes are coming from.

---

### Improper use of while loops.

A while loop like in:

```py
def calc_Num(num,dados):
    i=0
    Soma=0;
    while(i<5):
        if(dados[i]==num):
            Soma=Soma+num
        i=i+1
    return Soma
```

should just be a for loop. Notice that the variable is **always** incremented by the same amount in each iteration. I see at least 10 loops of this kind.

You can transform the loop, and improve the function, like so:

```py
def calc_num(num, dados):
    soma = 0
    for i in range(5):
        if dados[i] == num:
            soma += num
    return soma
```

In this particular case, we can simplify things even further,

```py
def calc_num(num, dados):
    return num * dados[:5].count(num)
```

at which point it should become obvious that there might not even be a reason for this function to exist, depending on how frequently it is used, amongst other things.

---

### Keep it simple, find common patterns.

Take this function:

```py
def str_Int(lista):
    i=0
    while(i<len(lista)):
        lista[i]=int(lista[i])
        i=i+1
    return lista
```

This function is not following naming/style conventions, contains a problematic while loop, mutates and returns its argument for no good reason, and can be eliminated entirely.

Improving the name, fixing the loop:

```py
def strs_to_ints(list_in):
    for i in range(len(list_in)):
        list_in[i] = int(list_in[i])
    return list_in
```

It becomes obvious that this is an extremely basic pattern: All you're doing is applying some function to every element in a list.

You can use a simple list comprehension instead:

```
my_list = [int(elem) for elem in my_list]
```

---

### Comparisons and operations on multiple values

```py
(1 and 2 and 3 and 4 in dados)
```

The code above, taken from your post, does not behave as you might expect. Try checking the value of `1 and 2`, and `1 and 2 in [2, 3]`.

This is a rather common source of confusion, often seen under the form `1 or 2 or 3 == my_val`.

---

### Infinite loop?

```py
def calc_Vencedor():
    i=0
    j=0
    PtMax=0
    pessoas=[]
    while(i<3):
        nome=get_nome_ind(i)
        Pt=calc_PontTotal(nome)
        pessoas.append([nome,Pt])
        if(Pt>PtMax):
            PtMax=Pt
        i=i+1
    print("O(s) vencedor(es) é(sao):")
    while(j<3):
        if(pessoas[j][1]==PtMax):
           print(pessoas[j][0])
```

Is the `while j < 3:` not an infinite loop, since the value of `j` is never changed?

---

Let me know if anything isn't clear :)

Comment: This code is not only mine, another person build it.  But, Thanks for the tips, at many points you are correct. But there is only point witch is  I don't understand.:"(1 and 2 and 3 and 4 in dados)
The code above, taken from your post, does not behave as you might expect"

Comment: I have done some tests in the terminal, and it looks ok.

Comment: >>> dados = [ 1 , 2 ,3 ,4 ,5]
>>> 1 and 2 and 3 and 4 in dados
True
>>> dados = [6,4,5,3,2,1]
>>> 1 and 2 and 4 and 4 in dados
True
>>> 1 and 2 and 3 and 4 in dados
True
>>> dados = [1,2,3]
>>> 5 and 6 in dados
False

Comment: @LucasVital Try the examples I suggested, it should make things clearer.